# Android Plugin in Eclipse 3.5 / 3.6 on Ubuntu 64bit got problems with properties

Tags: android, linux, eclipse-plugin, gnome

I got a huge problem with the Android Development Tools ADT running in Eclipse Galileo (3.5.1) on Ubuntu 9.10, 64bit.
**[Edit: as well on Ubuntu 10.10 and Eclipse Helios up to the latest 3.6.2!]**

On this platform, I do not manage to see any property edit dialogs for layout properties. E.g. the one where you can select a string resource ID for text fields, or a drawable ID for image fields or backgrounds.

Whenever I click on the `...` button next to the property value - nothing happens, except this button disappears.
Properties with a list of possible values, e.g. "wrap_content" or "fill_parent" are displayed in a dropdown box directly in the properties field.

On a different system I work in a Windows environment with Eclipse 3.4 and the same ADT: no problems whatsoever, everything works fine, the dialogs come perfectly.

Does anyone know what to do here? Where's the problem? Why does Eclipse not tell me that something goes wrong?

Thanks!

**NEW DISCOVERIES:** I found out that it might not even be an Android problem, but a general Eclipse problem that I can see with **all** version (Ganymede, Galileo, Helios) on my Linux (Ubuntu) system. It must be a simple UI problem: the button with `...` next to the values does not receive the mouse click!! I managed to see the appropriate dialogs to edit the property values by **doubleclicking** the button - crazy, strange, ugly behavior! But why on earth does nobody else know about this problem - I cannot find anything else on the net about it! Could it be related to this strange "GDK native window problem" on Gnome? HELP!

Comment: Did you check if any of the toolbox (Eclipse or Java for starter) is in 32-bits instead of 64?

Comment: Eclipse is 64bit - downloaded and installed it in any flavor (Java EE, Java, Classic), definitely 64bit. Whereas the JDK is installed using the standard package manager Ubuntu comes with. I am pretty sure it's 64bit, too. Will look later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sIMPLy PRESS THE SPACEBAR WHEN IN.

**Edit** (just to complete the answer):
Within the property when focused on the value, press *Tab* followed by *Space*. Reason: *Tab* moves to the small "..." button behind the value and *Space* depresses it.

Comment: Hey! Almost!! When the ... Button is there (so you are editing the entry) - press Tab and THEN Spacebar! Gee, works! But still: why don't they get rid of this annoying BUG!!!!!????

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I will now get rid of this open question - but still, it is a bug that I discovered here which I cannot find anywhere else and I don't know where to post.

The "..." button next to a property's value is not really "not clickable", it is "hard to click". With a quick double-click I am able to "reach" the handler, to let it act upon this event and the dialog box for editing a property's value opens.

But still: this is only the case on Linux with all available Eclipse versions. So I am not sure whether it's the Android Plugin's fault or Eclipse's fault...
*sigh*